# Pass dynamic database function to psycopg2 cursor.execute(statement, params)

Tags: python, postgis, psycopg2

I run the following statement through psycopg2 (which works):

```
self.cursor.execute( """INSERT INTO """ + self.config.schema + """.parcel (
    id,geometry) VALUES (%s, ST_GeomFromGML(%s))""", (self.id, self.geometry)
```

But now I need to introduce some dynamics and would like to try something like this:

```
if multi:
    mygeom = "ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromGml(" + self.geometry + "))"
else 
    mygeom = "ST_GeomFromGml(" + self.geometry + ")"

self.cursor.execute( """INSERT INTO """ + self.config.schema + """.parcel (
    id,geometry) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (self.id, mygeom)
```

Of course this will fail big time since it will parse the entire function as an escaped string. Is there anyone that has any experience of how to resolve database functions to parse them dynamically in the execute statement or is this impossible?

Answer (score 0):

```
if multi:
    mygeom = "ST_Multi(ST_GeomFromGml(%s))"
else:
    mygeom = "ST_GeomFromGml(%s)"

self.cursor.execute( """INSERT INTO {}.parcel (
    id,geometry) VALUES (%s, {})""" .format(self.config.schema, mygeom) , (self.id, self.geometry) )
```

I inserted the schema and function with a string `format` method. I also inserted `self.geometry` in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO {}.parcel (id,geometry) VALUES (%s, %s)".format( self.config.schema), (self.id, mygeom))